# Trigger Downtime programmatically using ResourceTaskStart .startTask(Agent)

Tags: anylogic, downtime

In my model I have a Resource Pool representing an equipment, which has a downtime defined by a Downtime block. The Downtime is defined by triggers and sends its tasks to a flowchart.

Besides the standard Downtime procedure I want to trigger a Downtime programmatically, using:

```
`cleaning_and_conditioning_mld_617_411.startTask(Eq_MLD_617_411);`
```

I get the following error:

`Eq_MLD_617_411 cannot be resolved to a variable`

How can I fix this?

Edit: changed the code to

```
cleaning_and_conditioning_mld_617_411.startTask(new Eq_MLD_617_411());
```

Now I get a NullPointerException (see Picture 6).

Please find attached pictures of the model.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xho4L.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8Ybx.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyPGH.png
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WX8f.png
[5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5M2lc.png
[6]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGB1W.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Eq_MLD_617_411` is the name of your ResourceUnit type. You will need to provide an actual resource unit for the downtime to start.

Unfortuantely you can't simply call
`cleaning_and_conditioning_mld_617_411.startTask(new Eq_MLD_617_411());`
because `new Eq_MLD_617_411()` will create a new agent but not have any connection to the engine. (hence you got the null pointer exception on `...engine.Utilities.time`

Instead, you need to always create agents using the AnyLogic provided `add_myPopulation()` which becomes available as soon as you create a population of any agent type on the canvas.

Now in your case, since you have a resource pool, we need to access the resource units that belong to that pool... yet there is no `resourcePool.getUnit()` function available... so now what?

One option is to add the resource units of the pool to a population that you create

[image]

And then you can call a resource unit from that population to start downtime

[image]

I tested it and pressing the button during run time reduces the available resources.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I changed the Code to:
`cleaning_and_conditioning_mld_617_411.startTask(new Eq_MLD_617_411());`
Now I get a NullPointerException (see EDIT in the OP).

Comment: Apologies Sebastian, my original answer missed an important aspect of creating agents programmatically, see the updated answer. Let me know if this helps